# Make lists with out commas in python

Tags: python, python-3.3

I want to make a list of list without comma.

```
data=[[2,124,123],[3,4,5]]
for i in data:
    print(x[0],x[1],x[2])
```

gives

```
2 124 123
3 4 5
```

How do I write the code so that it gives me:

```
[   2 124 123 ]
[   3   4   5 ]
```

for any kind of input with out using **built in** functions. The number of paddings for all elements is equal to the length of the  largest element in the the list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try 2 for loops if you're using a 2 dimensional list.

Answer (score 6):

Just unpack the arguments to print, eg:

```
data=[[2,124,123],[3,4,5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
for i in data:
    print(*i)
```

Gives:

```
2 124 123
3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

If you only wanted the first *n* many then slice it, then unpack it, eg:

```
for i in data:
    print(*i[:3])
```

Not sure what you mean by "without builtin" functions, as that just seems silly. Find the max length to pad, then apply it as such:

```
from itertools import chain

data=[[2,124,123],[3,4,5]]
max_padding = max(len(str(el)) for el in chain.from_iterable(data))
for i in data:
    print(' '.join([str(el).rjust(max_padding) for el in i]))
```

Gives:

```
  2 124 123
  3   4   5
```

If you actually want brackets around it, then it's easy enough to add them in...

Answer (score 1):

Is the below doing what you want?

```
for i in data:
   print("[" + ' '.join(str(x) for x in i) + "]")
```